# What does the term static variable mean in unix speak?

Tags: process, programming, terminology

From the section 2.7 of the book - [The Linux programing Interface](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1593272200) named **Process memory layout**  :

*Data* is defined as the

```
static variables used by the program.
```

What is the significance of the word static here ? I am aware of what static variables are in Java but I can not relate that meaning in this context .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Static variables are variables that exist throughout the lifetime of the program. That is, they are placed in memory allocated at compile time (as opposed to most variables, which are allocated at run time).

Answer (score 2):

This does not have an exact parallel in Java, but it is somewhat like static final properties of a class that are set in their definition.

C "const" constants are translated to "Data" in programs layout.

However, a write limitation doesn't necessarily exists in the machine code in the case of data, unlike in cases of constants or final variables.